# How to spare & group objects according key-value

Tags: json, jq

I'm new on this, those are my first steps. I guess I've started with a not simple case.

Let's see:
I have objects, with an ID (`name`) and a resource group (`rgs`). Each object may be part of several groups. And what a do need is to get the intersections of the groups.

It is important to say that the object may part of several groups, which are parent-child groups, and I just need to get the parent group. It is easy to identify the parenthoods as they share prefixes.

e.g. Group `PROM_FD_ARCNA` contains the child groups `PROM_FD_ARCNA_TGM` and `PROM_FD_ARCNA_TGM_TGA`.
And the child groups contains the objects itself. But, as long as I can get the information from object, it is over.

The parent groups are `PROM_FD_ARCNA`, `PROM_JOB_ICMP` and `PROM_JOB_WIN`. That is to say, I need to get those objects which belong to the intersections of those groups.

The JSON file which looks like:

```json
[
    {
        "id_ci": "487006",
        "name": "LABTNSARWID625",
        "id_ci_class": "host",
        "rgs": "PROM_FD_ARCNA, PROM_FD_ARCNA_TGM, PROM_FD_ARCNA_TGM_TGA"
    },
    {
        "id_ci": "5706",
        "name": "HCCQ2001",
        "id_ci_class": "host",
        "rgs": "PROM_JOB_ICMP"
    },
    {
        "id_ci": "9106",
        "name": "HCC02155",
        "id_ci_class": "host",
        "rgs": "PROM_FD_ARCNA, PROM_FD_ARCNA_TGA, PROM_JOB_ICMP"
    },
    {
        "id_ci": "2306",
        "name": "VM00006",
        "id_ci_class": "host",
        "rgs": "PROM_FD_ARCNA, PROM_FD_ARCNA_TGA, PROM_JOB_WIN, PROM_JOB_WIN_TGA"
    }
]
```

If my explanation was not good, I need to get a JSON like this:

```json
PROM_FD_ARCNA, PROM_JOB_ICMP
{
"HCC02155"
}

PROM_FD_ARCNA, PROM_JOB_WIN 
{
"VM00006"
}
```

As those are the intersections.

---

So far, I tried this:

```sh
jq '[.[] | select(.id_ci_class == "host") | select (.rgs | startswith("PROM_FD_ARCNA")) | .rgs = "PROM_FD_ARCNA"] 
| group_by(.rgs) | map({"rgs": .[0].rgs, "Hosts": map(.name)}) '  ./prom_jobs.json >> Step0A.json
```

```sh
jq '[.[] | select(.id_ci_class == "host") | select (.rgs | startswith("PROM_JOB_WIN")) | .rgs = "PROM_JOB_WIN"] 
| group_by(.rgs) | map({"rgs": .[0].rgs, "Hosts": map(.name)}) '  ./prom_jobs.json >> Step0A.json
```

```sh
jq '[.[] | select(.id_ci_class == "host") | select (.rgs | startswith("PROM_JOB_ICMP")) | .rgs = "PROM_JOB_ICMP"] 
| group_by(.rgs) | map({"rgs": .[0].rgs, "Hosts": map(.name)}) '  ./prom_jobs.json >> Step0A.json
```

And the result is:

```json
[
  {
    "rgs": "PROM_FD_ARCNA",
    "Hosts": [
      "LABTNSARWID625",
      "HCC02155",
      "VM00006"
    ]
  }
]
[
  {
    "rgs": "PROM_JOB_WIN",
    "Hosts": [
      "VM00006"
    ]
  }
]
[
  {
    "rgs": "PROM_JOB_ICMP",
    "Hosts": [
      "HCCQ2001",
      "HCC02155"
    ]
  }
]
```

Of course, the full JSON is quite long and I need to process this as lightweight as possible. Don't know if I've started well or bad.

Comment: Re "*I need to get a JSON like this:*", That's not even close to valid JSON

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
def to_set(s): reduce s as $_ ( {}; .[ $_ ] = true );

[ "PROM_FD_ARCNA", "PROM_JOB_ICMP", "PROM_JOB_WIN" ] as $roots |

map(
   {
      name,
      has_rg: to_set( .rgs | split( ", " )[] )
   }
) as $hosts |

[
   range( 0;    $roots | length ) as $i |  $roots[ $i ] as $g1 |
   range( $i+1; $roots | length ) as $j |  $roots[ $j ] as $g2 |
   {
      root_rgs: [ $g1, $g2 ],
      names: [
         $hosts[] |
         select( .has_rg[ $g1 ] and .has_rg[ $g2 ] ) |
         .name
      ]
   } |
   select( .names | length > 0 )
]
```

produces

```json
[
  {
    "root_rgs": [
      "PROM_FD_ARCNA",
      "PROM_JOB_ICMP"
    ],
    "names": [
      "HCC02155"
    ]
  },
  {
    "root_rgs": [
      "PROM_FD_ARCNA",
      "PROM_JOB_WIN"
    ],
    "names": [
      "VM00006"
    ]
  }
]
```

[Demo](https://jqplay.org/s/7rLRDrgTao) on jqplay

Comment: Could use `INDEX( …; . )` instead of `to_set( … )`.

Comment: Replace `[ $g1, $g2 ]` with `"\( $g1 ), \( $g2 )"` to get the same format as the input.